# Can I associate to an Imageview more than one Onclick method

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I'm a novice programmer and I've just begun creating some android applications and I was wondering if it's possible to associate to an Imageview more than one Onclick method. I'm trying to figure out the answer to this question because I have to connect two different methods and the relative instructions to the pression of the user on the image. First of all I thought about making just one method instead of two in order to optimize the code, but I've realized that I'm obliged to make two because, due to logic problems, some instructions can't coexist.

I apologize if there's already a similar question.

Comment: Can you show what your code looks like now? Could you not just call your two methods that you want to execute from the listener?

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I have already solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each view can only have own onClick event. You can, however, call multiple methods from the onClick event.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer